# A treatment of basic Kaluza-Klein theory

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, kaluza-klein

I'm looking for a treatment of the original basic [Kaluza-Klein theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory). 
Can someone recommend a review article or something?

Comment: Starting searches, easy to find more: http://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?q=Kaluza-Klein+theory, http://inspirehep.net/search?ln=en&ln=en&p=Kaluza-Klein&

Comment: There is an article "Kaluza-Klein theories" by David Bailin and Alex Love in Rep. Prog. Phys. 50 (1987). You can find it here http://bookos.org/. Search "Kaluza Klein Theories", it should be the first hit. Also, there are several other books on this topic on this site.

Comment: Hi Mouse.The.Lucky.Dog, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This isn't the place to ask for recommendations. If there's a particular concept having to do with KK theory that confuses you, you can of course ask about that (and people will refer you to books in the answers if they think it's useful to do so).

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky this is a reference request about a well defined not too broad topic again !!! It should NOT have been closed as reference requests are allowd as we said again yesterday. Could you at least stop shooting down such reference requests unilaterally and ask what other people think, for example in chat, before and let some close votes accumulate ?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky he is interested in a review article, not in books ...

Comment: @Dilaton this is not a reference request, it's a recommendation question. Remember, book recommendations don't just have to be for books. If the question were edited to contain criteria identifying a specific article or a small, bounded set of articles that the poster is looking for, then it would be a reference request and it would be fine to reopen.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I (and maybe others too?) will probably never understand what your criteria are for a reference-request question to be valid and deserving to stay alive and get answers... :-/ I just feel very lucky and furtunate that you obviously have not seen my own question asking for references about the gravity-fluid dynamics correspondence, such that I escaped with some nice hints in the form of answers. To me it looks trying to ask a reference-request question is pointless since all of them get closed, even though they should be allowed according to the corresponding meta discussion.

Comment: @Dilaton it's explained in the tag wikis and in [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/786). Posts which are actually reference requests, by that definition, are of course allowed. The things which get closed are generally not actual reference requests.

Answer (score 3):

How's this: http://www.weylmann.com/kaluza.pdf ?

Be careful though, because there are a couple *very* big errors that the author makes. For example in equation (6) there *should not* be a factor of 1/2 in front of the second term on the right-hand side. It should just be a factor of one. If you do the Christoffel symbol calculations and expand out the 5D geodesic equation, you'll get the following:

$$\frac{d^2 x^\lambda}{ds^2}+\begin{Bmatrix} \lambda \\ \mu \nu \end{Bmatrix} \frac{dx^\mu}{ds} \frac{dx^\nu}{ds}=-k\left ( \frac{dx^5}{ds} +A_\nu \frac{dx^\nu}{ds} \right )F^\lambda_{~\mu}\frac{dx^\mu}{ds}$$

In fact, the factor 1/2 that the author has in his paper keeps the equation from being gauge-invariant. Similarly, after equation (6) he says:

> This expression is now fully covariant, although the $A_\nu F^\lambda_{~\mu}$ term does not have any classical correspondence.

This is incorrect. It makes no sense to split up the terms, which is why I factored them like you see above. It actually turns out that Noether conserved momentum about the curled-up 5th dimension is:

$$-mk\left ( \frac{dx^5}{ds} +A_\nu \frac{dx^\nu}{ds} \right )$$

So it's a conserved quantity which is gauge-invariant. By comparison with the usual Lorentz Force Law, this conserved momentum is therefore associated with charge.

You should also note that in more modern treatments of KK theory $g_{55}$ isn't restricted to being a constant, and is promoted to a scalar field. Physically this means that the 5th dimension is allowed to have variable size.